# can we insert HTML tags in XSL Variable

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xsl-variable

I just want to confirm whether we can insert html tags inside the xsl variable?
example

```
<xsl:variable name="htmlContent">
<html>
<body>
hiiii
</body>
</html>
</xsl:variable>
```

if i use

```
<xsl:value-of select="$htmlContent"/>
```

I shoud get

```
<html>
<body>
hiiii
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible? i have tried

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$htmlContent"/>
```

Eventhough i am not getting the desired output

Comment: It should work. What output are you getting?

Comment: <htmlText>hii</htmlText> i have retrieved the value in the element called htmlText..I am getting like that

Comment: I think you aren't showing us everything. Where would <htmlText> come from?

Comment: <xsl:element name="htmlText">
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$htmlContent"/>
</xsl:element>
I wrote like this and i shud get 
<htmlText><html>
<body>
hiiii
</body>
</html>
</htmlText>

Comment: The code you are showing doesn't contain <xsl:element>. Please post a small but complete example that allows us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SrivatsavaSesham please tell us which xslt processor you are using (Msxsl, saxon, xlstproc etc)

Answer (score 19):

Do not use `value-of`, which gets the *text value* of the selected node. Instead use `copy-of`, which copies the entire tree (nodes and all) into the output:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$htmlContent"/>
```

Here is a full example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:variable name="htmlContent">
    <html><body>hiiii</body></html>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="htmlText">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$htmlContent"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will always produce the xml:

```
<htmlText>
    <html>
       <body>hiiii</body>
    </html>
</htmlText>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response,I have used copy-of then it is elemenating html tags and printing the content..:(

Comment: You may also need to use exslt/msxsl node-set() to tell the parser that the variable is a result tree fragment.

Comment: can you please write sample code to add that node-set(), I am not that much expert in xslt :P

Comment: @nonnb, since he is not performing any node operations on the variable, he doesn't need a node-set and a result tree fragment is fine.

Comment: @SrivatsavaSesham, I have added a full, tested example. This should be working for you. (Make sure you are viewing the raw output of the transformation and not having it interpreted by a browser.)

Comment: Thanks for your help,I have doubt,I need to put that content in element
<xsl:element name="htmlText"> <xsl:copy-of select="$htmlContent"/></xsl:element> can i do like this