# BR not getting converted to line break in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, html-email

I am using XSLT to generate email body as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>   
    <xsl:param name="Test"/>     
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <br/>Test: <xsl:value-of select="$Test"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the value of Test parameter is `"sample <br> sample"`
But in email body, i am getting the `<br>` tag as it is.
It's not getting converted to line break.
However, if i put it directly in XSLT template then it's working.
Only when the br tag is in the parameter value then it's not working.
Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can we insert HTML tags in XSL Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200567/can-we-insert-html-tags-in-xsl-variable)

Answer (score 1):

To have any chance to create more than a text node, you would neeed to use `<xsl:copy-of select="$Test"/>` instead of `value-of`. However, in that case you would need to make sure you pass a result tree fragment or node as the parameter value, not a string. If you pass a string, all you can do is use `<xsl:value-of select="$Test" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` and hope your processor and setup supports that.

Your example with a string parameter would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">   
    <xsl:param name="Test"><![CDATA[sample <br> sample]]></xsl:param>     
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <br/>Test: <xsl:value-of select="$Test" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and if supported then outputs e.g.

```
<html>
   <body><br>Test: sample <br> sample
   </body>
</html>
```

On the other hand, with a fragment as the parameter value and `copy-of`, as in

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">   
    <xsl:param name="Test">sample <br/> sample</xsl:param>     
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <br/>Test: <xsl:copy-of select="$Test" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you will get the same output with any processor. The only challenge might be passing in a fragment as a parameter value, in particular when run from the command line.

Comment: tried `disable-output-escaping="yes"` but didn't work. I am still able to see `<br>` tag in the email body.
can you please elaborate on the copy-of thing?

Comment: Ypu will need to elaborate first on which XSLT processor you use, how you pass the parameter, what kind of value (string or node) you pass.

Comment: If you look at http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZN9/1 which uses `xsl:copy-of` on a parameter having a fragment as its value you will see that is then outputs a `br` element while http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZN9 which uses `xsl:value-of` does not output a `br` element. You will need to check the API of your XSLT processor on how to pass in a node fragment to be able to use `xsl:copy-of` as indicated.

Comment: i am passing string value to the Test parameter.
I want that string to be converted into br tag.

Comment: If it is a string then, as you can see in http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZN9/2, the use of `disable-output-escaping` works as long as the processor supports it and the transformation result is serialized. Which processor do you use, how do you run the transformation?

Comment: Thanks for explaining with an example :)